# Gstream not recognizing souphttpsrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer

I'm trying to set up my iPad to use as a webcam for my xubuntu desktop. I've installed gstreamer and the gst-plugins-good package, but I can't get it to recognize souphttpsrc. I've tried something similar to this command:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://[ip-address-here]:80/live ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "souphttpsrc"
```

I think this might be a dumb question that I'm not able to find an obvious answer to: how do you make gst recognize souphttpsrc?

Comment: What `gst-inspect-1.0 souphttpsrc` does?

Comment: Same problem here... Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: @Jan Spurny - I also have the problem. Mine returns `No such element or plugin 'souphttpsrc'`